# How do I access Datastore using github.com/golang/appengine?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, yaml

I am using github.com/golang/appengine and its associated "datastore". I was hoping this package would allow me to use Datastore in a normal Go website. Unfortunately, my

```
c := appengine.NewContext(rq)
```

keeps giving my a "NewContext passed an unknown http.Request" error. My app.yaml contains

```
application: sdklessdatastoremusic
version: 1
runtime: go
api_version: go1

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: _go_app

vm: true
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
```

What should that YAML be, or is the problem elsewhere?

Comment: Are you wanting to use that package in a non appengine managed vm app? Because I don't think that will work. You'll need the sdk to have the datastore. You'll have to set your app up like you were doing a regular appengine application.

Comment: Then is `github.com/golang/appengine/datastore` useless?

Comment: No. It assumes there is an appengine datastore to talk to. It doesn't embed one for you.

Comment: You should have read my comment on your other question...  I guess you still have the wrong impression what the purpose of the appengine package is.

Answer (score 1):

The App Engine packages only apply for when you are running on App Engine itself, not elsewhere.